# Drop down values always selecting first value

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is my code for row updating event.My problem is when i select drop down and save it to database it always selects only first selection.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {


                int devopsid = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["devopsid"].ToString());

                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        for (int i = 5; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                    {
                            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                            ddl.ID = "ddl " + row.Cells[0].Text;
                            // ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                            // ddl.Items.Add("Yes");
                            //ddl.Items.Add("No");
                            // ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                            ListItem item1 = new ListItem("Yes", "1");
                            ListItem item2 = new ListItem("No", "0");

                            List<string> values = new List<string>() { "Yes", "No" };
                            ddl.DataSource = values;

                            ddl.DataBind();

                            row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
                            string ddlselected = ddl.SelectedValue;
                            if (GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text == DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Trim())
                            {
                                string query = " update devopstable set  " + GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text + "  = '" + ddlselected + "' where devopsid=@devopsid ";
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn1);
                                cnn1.Open();
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@devopsid", devopsid);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                cnn1.Close();
                            }


                    }
                }
            }
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                FillGrid();


        }
```

Comment: Wrap the `DataBind()` of the GridView in an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: I tried doing the same,But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

try to write save method in IsPostback in page_load

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (IsPostBack)
  {
      // wrap your save method in function and call here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data to your `drop-down` when the page is not `PostBack` on `PageLoad`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // be careful it should be not post-back.
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
      // bind and set data source of your drop-down here
  }

}
```